# changing a value inside a Map also change it on another Map

Tags: javascript

**Edit : Question marked as duplicate, but the duplicated post is not helping me fixing this issue. How can I modify the value of the map2 without changing the one from map1 ? ( [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) )**

I have 2 maps. The first one can be considered as a "Source of truth" that is initialized at loading of the page. I want to duplicate the content of the first map into a second one. So all my changes will be applied to the second map, and I will use my first one if I want to revert my changes.

But duplicating a map is the cause of a weird bug that change the content of the first map when the second one is changed.

```js
var map1 = new Map()
var map2 = new Map()

map1.set('1', 'one')
map1.set('2', {alpha:"NOT",beta:"MODIFIED"})
map1.set('3', 'three')
    
// Duplicate the content of the first map into the second one //
map2 = new Map(map1) //<-- this is probably because of that assignment 
    
var x = map2.get('2')
x.alpha = "why???"
x.beta = "how???"
//Why does the value of the map change when I edit the 'x' variable ?
// map2.set('2', x); is not required ?

console.log("MAP1 : " + JSON.stringify(map1.get('2')))
console.log("MAP2 : " + JSON.stringify(map2.get('2')))
```

But the snippet blow work well and won't modify the value of the first map (but I can't modify only a part of the content inside map2 with this method)

```js
var map1 = new Map()
var map2 = new Map()

map1.set('1', 'one')
map1.set('2', {alpha:"NOT",beta:"MODIFIED"})
map1.set('3', 'three')
    
// Duplicate the content of the first map into the second one //
map2 = new Map(map1) //<-- this is probably because of that assignment 
    
map2.set('2', {alpha:'but this', beta:'work ???'})

console.log("MAP1 : " + JSON.stringify(map1.get('2')))
console.log("MAP2 : " + JSON.stringify(map2.get('2')))
```

What is happening ?

Comment: the duplicate question answers why the second is working and the first is not. to get independent values, you could stringify the value and get a parsed value back ([`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)). this approach does not work for custom instances.

Comment: it would be easy to give a helping answer like to make a one level 'deep' copy of the map via spread-operator.

Comment: @Turo Nina scholz hopefully answered my question with the "JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())" method. But yea, stackoverflow is annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Because the key 2 contains an object.
When creating a new map , it duplicates the object reference and doesn’t really create a deep copy.
The only thing that is duplicated is the reference to address where this object is.
The other values are primitives , that are deeply duplicated by default